# Can't get injector in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, singleton, angular2-di

I have `DrawingDataService` that contains array of my data and different tools to draw this data. I want to use `DrawingDataService` like singleton in all of my tools.

I set `DrawingDataService` in AppModule providers list (to make as it singleton instance):

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
    AppComponent
],
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
],
providers: [
    DrawingDataService
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then I add injector in my tool:

```
export class LineTool extends BaseTool {

constructor(private injector: Injector) {

    super();

    let drawingDataService2 = this.injector.get(DrawingDataService);
```

And it says me that `this.injector` is null. 
Is it a good practice to make singleton service for storing data?

Comment: I get the same error even though I have `@Injectable()` set on my class.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this in next way:

```
constuctor( private drawingDataService: DrawingDataService)
```

And you can use it in next way:

```
this.drawingDataService.someMethod()
```